# TSQL Recursive CTE That Contains a SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table called T that has three rows as follows....

```
Id   allocation   multiplier   multipliedallocation  multipliedallocationsum
1    20.000       1.0008       20.016                100.052
2    50.000       1.0006       50.030                100.052
3    30.000       1.0002       30.006                100.052
```

I would like to use this table to produce some projection results that alter the allocation over a number of months as follows...

```
Id   allocation   multiplier   multipliedallocation  multipliedallocationsum  mnth
1    20.000       1.0008       20.016                100.052                  1
2    50.000       1.0006       50.030                100.052                  1
3    30.000       1.0002       30.006                100.052                  1
1    20.005       1.0008       20.021                100.050                  2
2    50.003       1.0006       50.033                100.050                  2
3    29.990       1.0002       29.996                100.050                  2
1    20.011       1.0008       20.027                100.052                  3
2    50.008       1.0006       50.038                100.052                  3
3    29.981       1.0002       29.987                100.052                  3
1    20.017       1.0008       20.033                100.054                  4
2    50.012       1.0006       50.042                100.054                  4
3    29.971       1.0002       29.979                100.054                  4

etc
```

The multipliedallocation on any row = the allocation x multiplier.

The multipliedallocationsum on any row = the sum of the multipliedallocation for that month

The allocation for month n is the multipliedallocation for month n-1 divided by the multipliedallocationsum for month n-1, multiplied by 100

This is the recursive cte SQL statement I have come up with so far, but it is not doing what I expect...

```
WITH Alloc (Id, allocation, multiplier, multipliedallocation, mnth)
AS
(
    SELECT Id, allocation, multiplier, allocation * multiplier AS multipliedallocation, 1 AS mnth
    FROM T
),
AllocProjected (Id, allocation, multiplier, multipliedallocation, multipliedallocationsum, mnth)
AS
(
    SELECT a.Id, a.allocation, a.multiplier, a.multipliedallocation,
    SUM(a.multpliedallocation) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Id, a.mnth), 1
    FROM Alloc a

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.Id,
    CONVERT(decimal(6,3), (a.multipliedallocation / a.multipliedallocationsum) * 100.0) AS allocation,
    a.multiplier AS multiplier,
    a.multiplier,
    a.multiplier * (a.multipliedallocation / a.multipliedallocationsum) * 100.0 AS multipliedallocation,
    SUM(a.multipliedallocation) OVER (PARTITION BY a.mnth) AS multipliedallocationsum,
    a.mnth + 1
    FROM AllocProjected a
    WHERE a.mnth < 24
)
SELECT * FROM AllocProjected
ORDER BY mnth
```

the multipliedallocationsum only seems to show multipliedallocation for a single row, not the sum of the multipliedallocation for the whole month (i.e. across 3 rows)

Comment: I think it's because the mnth hasn't been determined at time of execution (the mnth is being set at the same time as the window calculation so it doesn't know about the other pieces of the set yet. if you alter the select * to do the window calculation outside the CTE you may get what your after.

Comment: The problem is that the multipliedallocationsum needs to be calculated recursively, so is there a way of doing that without using a CTE?

Comment: having trouble with SQL server on fiddle... once it's up I'll look into this closer.